# Show message when condition within Feature fails

Tags: wix

When I add a *Condition* within a *Feature* to assure that IIS is installed, it is working as expected (it searches installed IIS, when feature is selected. No check, when feature is not selected):

```
<Feature Id="feat.WebApplication" 
    Title="Web Application" 
    Level="1" 
    ConfigurableDirectory="DIR.WEBAPP">

   <Condition Level="0">
       <![CDATA[Installed OR (IISMAJORVERSION AND IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7")]]>
   </Condition>

   <!-- ... -->

</Feature>
```

But - as documented in [Condition Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html) - it is not allowed to have a message within the condition. So the installation silently fails, whereas it shows a message when the condition is placed directly in the *Product* node.

How can I show a message also for conditions within features?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the Condition node, after reading about the `Level` attribute of the [Feature Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html),

> Sets the install level of this feature. A value of 0 will disable the feature. **Processing the Condition Table can modify the level value** (this is set via the Condition child element). The default value is "1".

by using `Condition` within feature you get the ability to disable or enable features depending on its own value for `Level`, because you can override it if the condition matches with the value of the `Level` attribute of the condition.

So the best would be to add some text about the precondition to the feature Description.

Comment: But that is what I am trying to do. I disable the feature, when IIS is not installed. Only I would like to display a simple error message in this case.

Comment: Well, I'm relatively new to WiX (in transition from MakeMsi). What I found (that told me that it seems not as easy) was this blog post [Feature conditions and UI – Joy of Setup](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/) and its comments, hope this to be useful